# Length of a projected line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

If a line is of true length x and is inclined in angles a,b,c with respect to the xy,yz,zx planes respectively , then how can i find the length of the projected line in the xy , yz and zx planes respectively ( x1,x2,x3 being the lengths in the projected planes .)

Answer (score 0):

$$ x1 = x \cos a $$

$$ x2 = x \cos b $$

$$ x3 = x \cos c $$

By definition inclination of a line to a plane is the *minimum* of all angles of all lines through the point in the plane make to the line.